# Oracle get top row from union of queries

Tags: oracle

I have a query that is union of 3 more comples queries. Some thing like below

```
SELECT 'type_one' as typename, typeid, typetitle from abc, def
UNION
SELECT 'type_two' as typename, typeid, typetitle from xyz, pqr
UNION
SELECT 'type_three' as typename, typeid, typetitle from mno, ijk
order by date desc
```

This above query say returns 15 records, ordered by date desc. I would like to get the record with 'type_two' and most recent date as the first row always ( there may be more than one row with 'type_two') , and then get the rest of records ordered by date desc. Can any one please point out a way to do this in Oracle? thank you

Answer (score 1):

Use a CASE to give different weights to the desired columns

```
SELECT 'type_one' as typename, typeid, typetitle from abc, def
UNION
SELECT 'type_two' as typename, typeid, typetitle from xyz, pqr
UNION
SELECT 'type_three' as typename, typeid, typetitle from mno, ijk
order by CASE WHEN typename='type_two' THEN 0 ELSE 1 END,date desc
```

Comment: This will give a result of all the records with type_two on the top, and then the rest below. I need only 1 record with type_two as the 1st record, and the rest should be the mix of all types ordered by date..Hope this is clear. thanks

Comment: Any ideas on how i can do this please?